# IBM MobileFirst Application crashes on IPhones that upgraded their IOS to 12 And the IPA is being distributed as an enterprise

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, provisioning-profile, ios12, ios-enterprise

My developed application remains in background and doesn't open on Iphones that upgraded their IOS version to 12.

When I run the application from Xcode into a real device it works just fine, the mentioned problem arise when trying to export the ipa and selecting "Enterprise" as a method of distribution.

note that when I select "Development" as a method of distribution; it works fine, the problem happens in the enterprise case only.

[This video explains it all](http://alawneh.info/upload/uploads/salesapp.mp4)

- The application is built using MobileFirst 7.1.
- The UI framework is ionic 1.
- Cordova version 3.6.4.
- XCode version is 10.
- My application is an enterprise application.

here are the logs

> error 10:44:05.109096 +0300
>
> SpringBoard [Application Center App] Bootstrap failed with error:
>
> error 10:44:05.109128 +0300
>
> SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for  with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID Application Center App" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID Application Center App, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x2831ce0d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={BKLaunchdOperation=launch_get_running_pid_4SB, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0xea2f][62], BKLaunchdJobLabel=UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0xea2f][62], NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such process}}, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0xea2f][62], BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}
>
> error 10:44:05.110497 +0300
>
> assertiond Failed to start job with error  {
>
> description = "Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0xea2f][62]";
>
> failureReason = "No such process";
>
> userInfo = {
>
> ```
>   BKLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0xea2f][62];
>
>
>   BKLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
> ```
>
> }
>
> }
>
> error 10:44:10.931924 +0300
>
> SpringBoard [Application Center App] Bootstrap failed with error:
>
> error 10:44:10.932136 +0300
>
> SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for  with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID Application Center App" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID Application Center App, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x283400270 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={BKLaunchdOperation=launch_get_running_pid_4SB, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0x63d8][62], BKLaunchdJobLabel=UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0x63d8][62], NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such process}}, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0x63d8][62], BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}
>
> error 10:44:10.939002 +0300
>
> assertiond Failed to start job with error  {
>
> description = "Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0x63d8][62]";
>
> failureReason = "No such process";
>
> userInfo = {
>
> ```
>   BKLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:Application Center App[0x63d8][62];
>
>   BKLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
> ```
>
> }
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest iFix [7.1.0.0-MFPF-IF201808161052](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/05/18/7-1-master-ifix-release/) and refer the blog for more details : [IBM MobileFirst and iOS12](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/09/17/IBM-MobileFirst-iOS12/)

Comment: I already applied the steps mentioned in this article "IBM MobileFirst and iOS12" before asking the question. it helped when I run it directly from xcode to mobile but the problem happens when I upload the exported ipa to the application center and then download the app for testing, and regarding the fixes, I installed them, still with no luck

Comment: 1.Do you see any errors in device logs? If yes can you share? 2.It happens only when you upload your app through application centre? Did you try to install using iTunes/Xcode device organiser ?

Comment: @SSuman99 I added the logs to the question, can you please check them out? regarding the crash it happens only when I export the IPA as an enterprise, also we did install it using Xcode device organizer and it didn't work

Comment: Looks like a provisioning issue in case of enterprise distribution.Can you raise a support ticket with us ?